# Which one is correct? “犯賤” or “泛賤”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

At [5:35](https://youtu.be/XKB9_x0UmX8?t=335), Louisa Mak (麥明詩) says

> 女孩是_賤.

Is the blank 泛 or 犯?

Answer (score 2):

泛 means "extensive"

犯 means "commit (crime/ mistake)"

The correct term is [犯賤](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/37933/)

> [犯賤](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/37933/)
>
> masochistic; sucker; asking for pain and suffering

Here is a [discussion](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?14,121553,121564) on the topic

Comment: For discussion sake, what would 女孩是泛賤 mean?

Comment: 泛賤 is not a thing.

Answer (score 0):

犯贱 [ fàn jiàn ] 行为不自重，显得轻贱。  Undignified behaviour, appear demeaning.

犯贱 [ fàn jiàn ] 骂人的话。指天生的贱骨头，只要人打骂。

Swear word, refers to a contemptible character who only deserves beating and scolding.

犯贱 [ fàn jiàn ] 英文翻译: Act bitchy

And somehow related (how?):

贱内：my wife

称谓。谦称自己的妻子。《红楼梦．第一○回》：「让我把贱内的病症说一说再看脉，如何？」

《文明小史．第一九回》：「这件事须要问我们贱内，目前就要进这不缠足会了。」也作「贱累」、「贱荆」、「贱室」。

骂人的话。指天生的贱骨头，只要人打骂。